# Как сделать переадресацию на другую страницу?

Tags: php, сессия

Вообщем , я в коде использовал сессии и массивы(для сессий) , теперь нужно что бы при логине меня автоматом перебрасывало на другую страницу , а функция session_start() и функция header() вместе не работают . Также пытался сделать все с помощью JS но он не переадресовует

Код PHP:

```
<?php 

require("mysqli/mysqli.php");
session_start();
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LOGIN</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
 <body>
<header>
  <?php 

  require("includes/header.php");

  ?>
</header>

<section>
<?php 
  //Функция для ошибок
function fail($fu){
  echo "Не введен $fu<br>";

}
$data = $_POST;
$error = array();

if(isset($data['button'])){
  if($data['login'] == ''){
    $error[] = fail('логин');
  }else{
    $log = trim($data['login']);
  }
  if($data['pass'] == ''){
    $error[] = fail('пароль');
  }else{
    $pass = trim($data['pass']);
   }
   if(empty($error)){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$log' and pass='$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con , $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1){
      $_SESSION['login'] = $log;
    }else{
      $fsmg = "Error";
    }
   }
 }
 if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
  $log = $_SESSION['login'];
  ?>
  <script language="JavaScript"> 
  window.location.href = "http://abcd.com/profile.php";
  </script>
  <?php  
  }

  ?>

  <form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <p>Логин</p>
  <input type="login" name="login"><br>
  <p>Пароль</p>
  <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Войти</button>
  </form>
  </section>

<footer>
   <?php 

   require("includes/footer.php")

   ?>
   </footer>
```

Comment: Покажите свой код и ваши попытки переадресации. Скорее всего вы не правильно написали переадресацию

Comment: функция session_start() и функция header() вместе прекрасно работают

Comment: Все , код добавлен@Yernar